Differences in Quantum Field Theory in 4 Spatial Dimensions
Since I'm thinking about doing some world building on the subject for a potential future story, I wanted to ask some questions on what the fundamental effects on physics in a universe with 4 spatial dimensions would be. For this question, assuming that Quantum Field Theory is at least close enough to a true description of how fundamental particles exist, would there being a 4th spacial dimension effect it in any meaningful way? To clarify, I'm not asking about all the individual subatomic particles or fundamental forces, I'm sure that those would change at least somewhat, for this question I'm wondering how 4D effects the idea of excitement in universal fields being used as a representation of particles and forces, like how a higgs boson is an excitation in the higgs field.

Welcome Stuckin. Pleaser take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. We generally solve problems, whereas you've asked a very broad question regarding a host of possible differences and properties of an hypothetical spacetime. Perhaps take a look at the dimension matrix/chart/thingy for background, then [edit] to ask something more specific.

Thanks for the advice escaped dental patient, I went ahead and specified the question as much as I could think to. Please let me know if you think I should clarify more or anything like that!

I'm going to avoid voting to close for a moment hoping that you can bring the question into conformance with Stack Exchange's rules. This is perhaps the ultimate example of an off-topic high concept question. It's proposing a seemingly "simple" change and asking what enormous consequences will occur. Too broad, open-ended, hypothetical... all things prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. You're literally asking how the fundamental nature of the universe changes in a world with 4D, which we can't even imagine. ...

... Therefore, like @Escapeddentalpatient., I'm going to ask you to consider carefully that you're on a service with a "one-specific-question/one-best-answer" model and need to [edit] your post to meet at least that basic expectation. (BTW, if you roll your mouse over the [tag:science-fiction] and [tag:hard-science] tags you'll learn they're mutually exclusive. It pays to read the tag wikis. You need to delete one... I strongly recommend deleting [tag:hard-science].)

Suggestion: You could take a look at the search results for dimensions on this site - see if you can get an idea of what you need to know, and find a way of asking it that's not either too broad or a duplicate. (Notice the closed ones and the reasons in the banners there).

Time is considered a quasi-"spatial" dimension as well. Even if it is not named like that in everyday language. Time describes the changes that happen on a 3D spot in space. So, do you mean you would like to have a 5D spacetime+X? On what are you focusing with that question? Do you have a certain being in mind that should or should not be affected from such changes?

QFT is a mathematical model that approximates behavior given our observations of this universe. There are two questions implied here. 1. What would a universe be like with a 4th dimension? 2. What would a QFT model be with an extra degree of freedom? Question 1 is not really answerable (though certain scenarios could be interesting). Question 2 has a mathematical answer, but mostly disinteresting for world building. Then there is M (string) theory, that predicts 10 or 11 dimensions.

"Would change at least somewhat": That's a gross understatement. Calculus works differently in $\mathbb R^3$ and in $\mathbb R^4$. Simply put, if space has four extended dimensions nothing works any longer. Forget about quantum field theory; plain old Newtonian gravity and plain old classical electromagnetism stop working.

@AlexP They don’t stop working. They do become critically unstable and this makes the formation of complex structures like atoms and solar systems virtually impossible, but it’s not like one cant formulate any 4+1D QFT. Just not one that would allow for anything like the Universe as we know it to evolve.

imo, for the reason stated in the high-concept meta question raised above, this question is probably not well answerable here. It would probably be better off being reframed (so as to no longer be about worldbuilding, and instead just about the behaviour of QFT in 4+1D, and the differences from its behaviour in 3+1D) and asked on the physics site

@controlgroup: They absolutely stop working. For example in ordinary three-dimensional space, the line integral of an electric field along a closed path is zero, which is kind of important. You cannot get this result in four-dimensional space.

I know it would obtain very different results not consistent with known theories - I mean to say that that doesn’t mean a self-consistent QFT can’t be constructed, just that it wouldn’t be anything like ours, and trying to writing a story in that world would be futile. Fundamentally we agree that adding another dimension would break everything. @AlexP

Frame challenge: there is no story to take place in this world
You’ll have a hard time writing an interesting story in this world because, in anything other than a 3+1-dimensional spacetime and thus inverse-square gravity as well as 3 spatial dimensions, stable closed orbits do not exist even in Newtonian gravity. The only stabilizing forces are $F\propto r$ forces (simple harmonic oscillators) and $F\propto \frac{1}{r^2}$ forces (inverse-square forces like three of the four fundamentals, barring confinement). This is stated as Bertrand’s theorem and has been proven.
This might not seem like a huge issue but as it turns out in 4+1D spacetime (and thus $F\propto\frac{1}{r^3}$ gravity) this means that satellites orbiting their primary don’t have a consistent orbit; they either oscillate between a minimum and maximum radius $r_\mathrm{min}$ and $r_\mathrm{max}$ or spin off to infinity. In general, such a system is not stable if there is more than one satellite involved, be it stars around a galactic center or planets around a star or moons around a planet; with multiple planets (which is highly likely given how we’ve observed planets to form; planets are much smaller than the accretion disks that make them), it is likely that they will interact with each other in unpredictable ways and either crash into one another, toss themselves into the Sun, or throw themselves into the cold void of space.
This inverse-cube law isn’t new for just gravity, either. The electromagnetic force is also modified: the reason we have inverse-square laws in 3+1D spacetime is because the surface area of a sphere (i.e. the size of the surface over which a uniform burst of electromagnetic/gravitational radiation is emitted) varies inversely with the square of the radius in 3+1D. In 4+1D the surface area of the hypersphere over which a burst of radiation would be distributed varies inversely with the cube of the radius, which in turn leads to inverse-cube laws for things like gravity and electromagnetism which are mediated by photons and gravitons (radiation). Electromagnetism behaving differently would radically change the entirety of QFT in ways that would be mentally and physically exhausting to explain here, would screw up chemistry in ways that I can’t even rightly predict on my own, and would thus mess with biology in ways that I have a hard time even thinking about. The one thing I can say is that, like planets around the Sun, electron orbitals would be unstable as well and it is unlikely that, in this ultra-chaotic Universe, life would ever come to evolve.
Point being, the world would not be one in which any interesting stories take place. Perhaps revise the concept so that only a certain volume of space has this property; maybe an advanced civilization learned to reverse the compactification of a certain dimension to give the apparent 4 spatial dimensions say on a given planet or solar system.
So if you’re asking about QFT to think about the nitty-gritty details of the world as you prepare to write in it, be warned: your Universe was dead on arrival, and likely contains no life.
Wait, but that’s no fun!
Yeah, it’s not. Physics is specific, and if it were off, we’d all be either dead or never born. If you handwave a physical god coming ex nihilo to flash a bunch of life into existence on a planet orbiting a star alone in a “stable” configuration, the inhabitants of the planet (aside from having wildly-chaotic biochemistries) would see some interesting effects, most notably the instability of their own orbit: the seasons would be unpredictable without numerical analysis of the current state of the planet in space, since the planet would drift all around the habitable zone of the star over the course of 360 degrees around its star. Might want to set $r_\mathrm{min}$ and $r_\mathrm{max}$ within the habitable zone so that they don’t all freeze/incinerate and die.
Why changes to QFT matter at this point is a good question. Life probably won’t last long anywhere in the Universe if we don’t let some external force make it so, and that force has to originate within this Universe (multiversal astronauts would instantly fall apart at the molecular level upon entering this Universe). At this point, it’s better just to wave some hands. Your readers care about the story, not higher-dimensional quantum field theory.

I do not think that this orbit stability problem would be such a high issue. My reasoning is that long-term orbital perturbations can cause also major effects even in our 3D, and the result is that the stable planetary orbits regulate themselves into roughly circular and exponentially growing radius. I am nearly sure in a very similar result also in more spatial dimensions.

My reasoning is analogic to the micro-world. I do not see, how would an $\frac{|r|}{r^4}$ potential well make things so bad, if our current $\frac{|r|}{r^3}$-related potential wells, the question is in most practical problems: do we have an energy for an ionization or not. Yes, of course, chemistry would be really, really different - already electromagnetism would be likely very different, imagine for example that Faraday tensor would be 5x5 instead 4x4. Maybe we would have a third field beside electric and magnetic field.

The issue is that there do not exist any closed orbits in $F\propto r^{-3}$ systems, so climates on planets wouldn’t be nearly as stable as they are in 3+1D. I’m not sure what you mean by exponentially growing radius; that would just mean spiraling towards infinity which still kills everything on the planet.

Sorry but that is not true. A circular orbit can exist in any dimensions. One can calculate the radius by an elemental, not even differential equation: centripetal force should equal gravity, done. I think the reality behind this statement is that there are practically no elliptical orbits, there are elliptic-like orbits with a very strong precession.

Exponentially growing radius: in many-body systems with a big central body, long term state is that planetary orbital radius grow roughly exponentially and they are roughly circular. Like in the solar system. I have heard this "no stable orbit" thing so many times, and I am so sorry but it looks so strongly as the school example of a factoid!

The planetary orbital radius remains constant without external influence, as is the case for all eight planets of the Solar system. Eccentric orbits are also perfectly stable. It is also the case that closed orbits do not exist in higher-dimensional gravity that disobeys $F\propto r^{-2}$; this has been rigorously proven. @GraySheep

No, it grows roughly exponentially, like here can you see: https://web.njit.edu/~gary/202/Lecture7.html Table in the middle, third column. Another important thing, they are mostly circular and co-planar. Neither of the rules are exact but odds is that it is the result of some self-regulating mechanism.

You mean that the orbital radius grows exponentially with distance; yes, that is true. But it is also a fact that there aren’t closed orbits for systems with forces proportional to $r^x$ for $x\neq 1$ or $-2$.

Orbital radius grows exponentially with the number of the planet. There is the third column, check the numbers. After you have understood that it is close to an exponentially growing series, I think we could happily talk.

There is even some experimental rule for that, $0.4+0.3*2^n$ AU. It does not match for MErcury (only if $n=-infty$), neither for Pluto, but it is a close match for the others. I really can not understand why is it so f...g hard to understand in it. And yes, yes, yes, there is f...ly no reason to close out 3+ D only because some equations match well only in 3D. That is all. "there is no stable orbit in 3+ D" is the largest bullshit well known in physics, that is all!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
